# Setting up your own Proxys

Tags: proxy-server

I have a computer in UK, connected to internet but behind a firewall. I can remote desktop it using Logmein.

Now currently I am in UAE. Due to their censorship policies, I can't access certain websites/software.

What I want to do is somehow 'instruct' my computer here to 'access' my computer in UK for all its internet needs. This way I will be able to bypass the

Comment: Which operating systems do you have on these computers?

Answer (score 1):

Is tor available in UAE?  If you can hit tor you can get to almost anything...even better is using a tor hidden service.  It is slow though.

If you want to not use tor, you can use proxychains instead like so:

```
proxychains commandname
```

you would need to configure the appropriate proxy server address and protocol and start a proxy server on your UK PC.

another options is to proxy through ssh

Answer (score 0):

Or use a VPN proxy service

https://www.ipredator.se/

https://www.relakks.com/?cid=gb